# I can't figure out where to place my second Scanner close, does anyone know if I need add second or do I need an If statement where the while loop is?

Tags: java

So, I was getting a resource leak because I wasn't closing the scanner. I fixed the first one but am having an issue with the second scanner in the showTax() function. Is it as simple as finding the right placement for a second keyboard.close() or do I need to adjust my loop and add an If statement?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PropertyTaxCalculator {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int lotNumber;

        System.out.println("Enter the property's lot number");
        System.out.print("(or enter 0 to end): ");

        lotNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

            while (lotNumber != 0) {
                showTax();

                System.out.print("Enter the next Property's lot number (or 0 to end): ");

                lotNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
                
            }
    keyboard.close();    
    }

    public static void showTax() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        double propertyValue, tax;

        final double TAX_FACTOR = 0.0065;

        System.out.println("Enter the Property Value: ");
        propertyValue = keyboard.nextDouble();

        tax = propertyValue * TAX_FACTOR;
    
        System.out.println("The property's tax is $" + tax);
   
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need either of them actually. It is bad practice to close `System.in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better for you to make the Scanner a field of the class:

Edit: Make sure the keyboard field is static, as it is being referenced from static methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PropertyTaxCalculator {
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int lotNumber;

        System.out.println("Enter the property's lot number");
        System.out.print("(or enter 0 to end): ");

        lotNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (lotNumber != 0) {
            showTax();

            System.out.print("Enter the next Property's lot number (or 0 to end): ");

            lotNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
            
        }
        keyboard.close();    
}

public static void showTax() {
    double propertyValue, tax;

    final double TAX_FACTOR = 0.0065;

    System.out.println("Enter the Property Value: ");
    propertyValue = keyboard.nextDouble();

    tax = propertyValue * TAX_FACTOR;

    System.out.println("The property's tax is $" + tax);

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense. Still in my first programming class and learning static.

Comment: Nice. You should mark the question as answered if it's what you want